# How to show <div> tag literally in <code>/<pre> tag?

Tags: html, blogger

I'm using `<code>` tag inside of a `<pre>` tag to show code on my blogger blog. Unfortunately it doesn't work with HTML tags. Is there any way to show "`<div>`" inside of `<pre>` or `<code>` tag without actually interpreting it as HTML? This is what I do right now:

```
<pre>
 <code>
 .class {        
   color:red;
 }
 // I would like HTML code inside this
 </code>
</pre>
```

Which works ok for everything except HTML. Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape < and > inside <pre> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182/how-to-escape-and-inside-pre-tags)

Comment: What you really want is a `<![CDATA[]]>` section; good luck waiting for the browser authors to catch up with 1988 in between adding kewl feetchers.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

> Unfortunately it doesn't work with HTML tags.

`<code>` means "This is code", `<pre>` means "White space in this markup is significant". Neither means "The content of this element should not be treated as HTML", so both work perfectly, even if they don't mean what you want them to mean.

> Is there any way to show "`<div>`" inside of `<pre>` or `<code>` tag without actually interpreting it as HTML?

If you want to render a `<` character then use `&lt;`, with `&gt;` for `>` and `&amp;` for `&`.

You can't (in modern HTML) write markup and have it be interpreted as text.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using this tool now to escape HTML characters: http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html

Comment: @XedinUnknown — And [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/Overview.html) it says that you shouldn't reference that document. If you are right then **every browser on the planet** is not standards-compliant. You are not right. [The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element) describes the content model of a pre element and it can contain elements. Compare to [textarea](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-textarea-element) which can only contain text.

Answer (score 62):

It seems like a readonly textarea does pretty much what you want.

```
<textarea readonly> <!-- html code --> </textarea>
```

Comment: I would like some clarification why this has been voted down.  The textarea tag allows literal HTML code.  I just happen to be using it to display literal HTML when I came across this question and the answers seems rather complicated compared to just using a textarea.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in case anyone cares, it looks like character references are still parsed inside `<textarea> … </textarea>`, e.g. `&gt;` turns into `>`. This does mean it's not the "raw" contents anymore.

Comment: This is a good answer, the only reason I can see someone using codes like &gt; would be the default styles of textarea. Otherwise, this is my go-to option whenever I need to do this in my code.

Answer (score 35):

You can use the "xmp" element. The `<xmp></xmp>` has been in HTML since the beginning and is supported by all browsers. Even it should not be used, it is broadly supported.

Everything inside `<xmp></xmp>` is taken as it is (no markup lke tags or character references is recognized there) except, for apparent reason, the end tag of the element  itself.

Otherwise "xmp" is rendered like "pre".

Comment: This tag is obsolete.

Comment: @UsmanAhmed Be that as it may - the `xmp` is used by nice stuff like embedding `markdown`

Comment: `xmp` may be deprecated, but it is still HTML spec to support it to this day (which is why all major browsers do). I'd imagine it never gets fully deprecated, as it's the only tag of its kind and is more widely used today than it was when it was deemed deprecated.

Comment: Still working in Chrome two years later, thanks for the answer that solved my problem.

Comment: HTML Spec says:

_Use pre and code instead, and escape "<" and "&" characters as "&lt;" and "&amp;" respectively._
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#xmp

Answer (score 20):

Try:

```
<xmp></xmp>
```

for exemple:

```
<pre>
     <xmp><!-- your html code --></xmp>
</pre>
```

bye

Comment: Works well but according to documentation, it's deprecated... Too bad because it's awesome :-D

Comment: Roland gave the same answer a year earlier and with more detail so this is a duplicate.

Comment: bye......... :)

Answer (score 10):

Just escape the HTML tags. For example -

Replace **<** with `&lt;`

Replace **>** with `&gt;`

Complete lookup [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119042828/http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)

Answer (score 5):

This can be easily achieved with a little bit of javascript.

```
document.querySelectorAll("code").forEach(el => el.innerText = el.innerHTML);
```

Run snippet below to see it in action:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("code").forEach(el => el.innerText = el.innerHTML);
```

```css
pre {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
   .class {        
     color:red;
   }
   
   // I would like HTML code inside this
   <h1>Hello this is a heading</h1>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try CodeMirror (https://codemirror.net/)

It's a lightweight library that styles code in HTML. Here's a screenshot of what I'm referring to:

[image]

Worked well for us!

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but you could try to put a comment inside the tag like this:

```
<pre>
    <code<!-->>
        ...
    <<!-->/<!-->code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<pre>
  <code><textarea>
    <div>Now you can write Tags inside pre tag!</div>
  </textarea><code>
 <pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need an opening tag, e.g `<span>`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('code').forEach(codeElement => {
    codeElement.innerText = `<${codeElement.innerText}>`;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score -4):

Yes, with an escape xml function. You'll need to have jQuery enabled for it to work though.

```
<pre>
  ${fn:escapeXml('
    <!-- all your code -->
  ')};
</pre>
```