# Display LIVE Preview Of Textarea Front End Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my project I have a div which is a **text area** where I can wrap text in to code format.

I also have a **button** with a `id="preview"`

Is it possible in another div to display the **output** of the **text area** once click on preview button in a front end view like what it would be like on IE or FIREFOX.

**Codepen Example:** http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/lfpKF

**HMTL Code**

```
<div class="container">
<textarea id="widget">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus repellendus inventore, voluptatum ipsa ipsum debitis voluptates, laudantium nulla odio sed, pariatur quaerat quae numquam beatae ad odit optio quasi magni explicabo tenetur. Consectetur, animi, autem? Non laboriosam ad nisi, commodi, dolores soluta. Dolorum error unde itaque ipsum a? Libero sapiente eligendi similique, itaque deserunt aliquid magnam ducimus nesciunt, iste ad nihil labore assumenda soluta earum. Rerum deserunt totam aperiam maiores facere eum sapiente modi non debitis consectetur voluptatum, voluptatibus labore repellendus tempora voluptate error nesciunt eaque possimus. Consectetur laborum ab ipsum, voluptate perspiciatis quos omnis delectus dicta mollitia atque voluptates!</textarea>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="code">Code</button>
    <button id="preview">Preview</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Should display live out put of wraped code.-->
  <div id="preview" class="code-preview"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function wrapText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
    var textArea = $('#' + elementID);
    var len = textArea.val().length;
    var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
    var end = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    var replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag;
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
}

$('#bold').click(function() {
    wrapText("widget", "<strong>", "</strong>");
});
$('#italic').click(function() {
    wrapText("widget", "<em>", "</em>");
});
$('#underline').click(function() {
    wrapText("widget", "<u>", "</u>");
});
$('#code').click(function() {
    wrapText("widget", "<pre><code>", "</code></pre>");
});
```

Comment: see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvcBj

Comment: If I have wrapped the text in code tags and the click on preview not out putting it in code.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rutDC Are you using <pre>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your ID of preview button, like this:

```
<button id="preview-btn">Preview</button>
```

And in your JS:

```
$('#preview-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#preview').html($('#widget').val());
});
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyLai)

Comment: Does not allow me to wrap html and php code in pre/code tags

Comment: @acoderslife You should escape `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386586/how-to-show-div-tag-literally-in-code-pre-tag).

Comment: I tried that produces blank places the pre code tags at top of div does not wrap it when have other code even when use   &gt; http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/lfpKF

Comment: @acoderslife Bypass `&` with `&amp;`. See the [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbClB).

Comment: Still does not code tag button does not wrap div tags still even with that very strange show this <pre><code></code></pre> on top does not wrap it when div tags tried every thing I can think of.