# Display complete Javascript tag in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to place an entire javascript function in a div and show it for testing purposes, how can I accomplish this? I am doing this from code behind in asp.net

EDIT

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Website Purchase -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
 var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
  var fbds = document.createElement('script');
  fbds.async = true;
  fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
  _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
  })();
  window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm aware how odd of a request this is :)

Comment: I think that you can just place it in a div with `$("#selector").html("function(){ console.log('bla'); }");`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsh5sy1w/)? or better like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsh5sy1w/1/).

Comment: That's close, I also need the script tags to show

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: You need to do some trickery: [How to show <div> tag literally in <code>/<pre> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386586/how-to-show-div-tag-literally-in-code-pre-tag) Which says that you need to escape your `<` and `>` characters in your tag to `&lt;` and `&gt;` for them to show in the `<pre>`. The example below has been modified to show this.

You should try using the html `<pre>` tag, it's commonly supported and does exactly what you're asking for:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

```
<pre>
  &lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
    console.log('hi');
  &lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

should show something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log('hi');
</script>
```

Comment: I tried <pre> and it didn't work. I'll post the code.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, IE , Chrome.