# How to mix text and HTML tags inside <pre> with Jade without removing newlines?

Tags: pug

I would like the generated HTML to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <pre>First line
<em>Second line</em>
Third line</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried using:

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    pre.
      First line
      em second line
      third line
```

But it doesn't work, because `pre.` considers everything under it to be text. So I tried removing it and using `|` instead, as in:

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    pre
      | First line
      em second line
      | third line
```

But this puts everything inside the `pre` on a single line, as in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <pre>First line<em>second line</em>third line</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which is not what I want. As far as I can see, my only option is to embed HTML in Jade, as in:

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    pre.
      First line
      <em>second line</em>
      third line
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want ***escaped*** HTML

```
pre.
    First line
    &lt;em&gt;second line&lt;/em&gt;
    third line
```

or with the use of `#{}` :

```
pre.
    First line
    #{"<em>second line</em>"}
    third line
```

Comment: Didn't know about `#{}`, thanks. But what I'd like to do is to avoid writing HTML in Jade.

Comment: Checkout [How to show <div> tag literally in <code>/<pre> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386586/how-to-show-div-tag-literally-in-code-pre-tag)