# How do you showcase html code within a html page?

Tags: html

When i say this, i mean how do i make a specific piece of code show not as part of the actual website, but as a demonstration for others to see?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show <div> tag literally in <code>/<pre> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386586/how-to-show-div-tag-literally-in-code-pre-tag)

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do so

1. You may use `<pre></pre>` tag

```
<pre>
   your-code
</pre>
```

2. using special `<code>` tag

```
<pre>
  <code>
    your-code
  </code>
</pre>
```

3. you may like to use the HTML code within

```
<![CDATA[<your-code>]]>
```

4. use any syntax highligtening library e.g. [prettify](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify) or [syntaxhighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use:

1. The `<pre>` - Preformatted tag to display the html text
2. The `&lt;` - Less than tag in place of **<** tag in your code
3. The `&gt;` - Greater than tag in place of **>** tag in your code.
   i.e `<div>` shall be replaced by `&lt;div&gt;`

Brief example

```html
<pre>
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;body&gt;

&lt;h1&gt;The code element&lt;/h1&gt;

&lt;p&gt;The HTML &lt;code&gt;button&lt;/code&gt; tag defines a clickable button.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;The CSS &lt;code&gt;background-color&lt;/code&gt; property defines the background color of an element.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
<code>
you code here 
</code>
</pre>
```