# PHP preg_replace is outputing me the wrong result

Tags: php

Im actively practicing with php regex and got stuck with a replace function as it shows absolutely different results from tutorial I copied it from.

So the function `preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/', '(?P<\1>[a-z-]+)', '{controller}\/{action}')` **should** give me this result in the output: `(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<action>[a-z-]+)`. phpliveregex.com confirms that https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/wIF

However, this is what my browser on my localhost is outputing me in fact: `(?P[a-z-]+)\/(?P[a-z-]+)`.
How is that possible? Is my php broken or the preg_replace function is working differentely now? My php version is 7.4.4

Comment: maybe your browser interprets the `<controller>` and `<action>` as html tags and tries to parse them that leads to deleting them.

Comment: Using the `htmlspecialchars` function ending up working for me

Answer (score 0):

Your browser interprets the `<controller>` and `<action>` as html tags and tries to parse them that leads to deleting them. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386586/how-to-show-div-tag-literally-in-code-pre-tag) to see how can you show tags literally using html encoding.

```html
(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<action>[a-z-]+)

<br/>

(?P&lt;controller&gt;[a-z-]+)\/(?P&lt;action&gt;[a-z-]+)
```

You can maybe replace it with `(?P&lt;\1&gt;[a-z-]+)`