# How to place code snippets in html based Website?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place code/snippets (HTML5/ASP.NET, CSS3, Javascript, and C#) on a website without the browser giving an error. I thought the html5 `code` element would cause the browser to ignore the text between to opening and closing tags and render it just as text, however that is not the case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace all `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape < and > inside <pre> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182/how-to-escape-and-inside-pre-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Use the pre tag

```html
        <pre>
            if ($(this).hasClass('next-product')) {
                if (actualIndex === fancyImages.length - 1) {
                    actualIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    actualIndex++;
                }
                $.fancybox.next();
            } else {
                if (actualIndex === 0) {
                    actualIndex = fancyImages.length - 1;
                } else {
                    actualIndex--;
                }
                $.fancybox.prev();
            }
        </pre>
```

[definition](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

This works fine for any code if you want to display html entities then you must replace ">" and "<" programmatycally with "&gt" and "&lt".

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags like `<pre>` and `<code>` work in many cases, you have to manage characters like `<` `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Besides that if you are looking for a plug-in, the you can you [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/), work for snippets of different programming language.

Answer (score -1):

The usual approach is to replace `<` with `&lt;`, i.e. the entity equivalent, to invalidate the tag and so avoid the browser parsing it.

You don't have to do this manually; you can do this on a global replacement basis via whatever language you're using. For example, using JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<code>
    <div>Please don't parse this as a DIV, browser</div>
</code>
```

JavaScript (and jQuery, for brevity):

```
$(function() {
    $('code').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/</g, '&nbsp;'));
    });
});
```

In the DOM, this will result in:

`&lt;div>Please don't parse this as a DIV, browser&lt;/div>`

...meaning the user will see the code, not its parsed equivalent.