# <pre> not working well with <iostream> for C++ Code

Tags: html, include, pre

I want to show the text below

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
```

in my HTML file. I know that we have to use the HTML `pre` tag, but when I do so, I can only see  `#include`.

In fact, I am not able to include the code on Stack Overflow; it is showing me only `#include`.

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape < and > inside <pre> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182/how-to-escape-and-inside-pre-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `<` and `>` (HTML reserved characters), with their respective HTML entities : `&lt;` and `&gt;` :

```
<pre>
  #include &lt;algorithm&gt;
  #include &lt;iostream&gt;
</pre>
```