# PrismJS Code Highlighting issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to use prismjs http://prismjs.com/download.html for code highlighting, but it is not working see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/939u16ac/ I am getting the rendered HTML instead of the markup PFA markup and Screenshot

**HTML File:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Demo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/prism.css">
        <script src="lib/prism.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="">

<pre class="line-numbers language-markup">
<code  class="">
<ol type="1">
<li>
href atribute is must and id, class, title attribute are optional 
</li>
<li>
In angular application or you are not having any navigation link, use <b>javascript:void(0)</b> in href attribute value
</li>
</ol>
<a id="optionalID" class="optionalClass"  title="optionalTitle" href="Product.html" >Product Page</a>
</code>
</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Could any one spot me where i went wrong in implementing it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need to convert the `<` to HTML entities. Replace `<` with `&lt;` for all instances within your `code` tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show <div> tag literally in <code>/<pre> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386586/how-to-show-div-tag-literally-in-code-pre-tag)

Comment: @Harry: Thanks for the help. It will be much better if the indentation and this conversion taken care by the code. Put  it in the answer section.

Comment: Not adding an answer because the answer is going to be a dupe. Consider upvoting the answer in the linked thread (not mine) if it helped :)

Comment: @harry that question also seems duplicate, so mine is duplicate of duplicate :)....original Qn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182/how-to-escape-and-inside-pre-tags... and i thought it is taken care by the sytnax highlighter tool

Comment: Hmm yeah. You are correct :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape < and > inside <pre> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182/how-to-escape-and-inside-pre-tags)