# Writing HTML in a paragraph so it displays on the webpage

Tags: html

For school I have to build a website and on that website explain how I made it. The problem is i have to write a few snippets of HTML to show the teacher what I've done. The problem is when I put HTML in a paragraph nothing shows up.

for example

```
<p><div id ="something"></div></p>
```

But when I do this nothing shows up. How should I be writing it so it does?

Comment: You need to **escape** HTML by changing all `<` to `&lt;` and all `>` to `&gt;`. There might be more you have to do. You can use a free online converter like this: http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape < and > inside <pre> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182/how-to-escape-and-inside-pre-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show HTML in a web page you need to translate the `<` and `>` to their respective [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity),`&lt;` and `&gt;`, so they aren't rendered as HTML.

For example

```html
<p>&lt;div id ="something"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can escape HTML by using `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities.

```html
<p>&lt;div id ="something">&lt;/div&gt;</p>
```

Comment: You had a totally different answer and now changed it so that it's essentially identical to mine. Why?

Comment: @j08691 not really identical because you're using the pre-formatted tag and also, of course, I will change my answer to accommodate what OP wants. However, i did **NOT** attempt to make my answer similar to yours

Comment: Another user commented on my answer why I had `</pre>` in my answer to which I replied that it was a typo. The user deleted their comment and then I deleted my reply. Either way, your original answer was completely different yet you chose to change it to what I had already posted. I don't see the need for that.

Comment: And don't forget, your answer is still not technically correct as HTML entities and with `;`, which all of your are missing. Maybe you want to edit it. Again.

Comment: @j08691 I agree I had a different answer initially because OPs question was ambiguous, However after seeing the "Possible duplicate" that is suggested by comments under the question then I realised that is what OP wanted and I had to adapt my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xmp><div id="something"></div></xmp>
```

renders text between the start and end tags without interpreting the HTML in between and using a monospaced font

Comment: The `<xmp>` element is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp)