# Less than sign not working properly in drop down list in android studios

Tags: java, android-studio, drop-down-menu, spinner

I have a dropdown list with "Alert When >" and "Alert When <", but for some reason it wouldn't let it do "Alert When <" without throwing an error. It thinks the "<" is part of the the closing tag. I tried escaping it with "\" or even "\" but nothing is working. What can I do to fix this?

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string-array name = "numbers">
    <item> Alert When > </item>
    <item> Alert When < </item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape < and > inside <pre> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182/how-to-escape-and-inside-pre-tags)

Comment: Yeah, try using the character escape codes `&lt;` for `<` and `&glt;` for `>`.