# how to write < inside an HTML element

Tags: html

I want to know how I can write some text in HTML without it being interpreted as a tag? I tried writing `<p> <some text> 0</p>`  inside a paragraph and it only displays **0**

Comment: Recommended article to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape < and > inside <pre> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182/how-to-escape-and-inside-pre-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Escape sequences](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) are used to display a character which may otherwise be unsafe if used literally.
For a less-than sign (`<`) use `&lt;`
For a greater-than sign (`>`) use `&gt;`.

Answer (score -1):

`&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`